# Handling child.Click() when element is not in the viewport and there is no element ID

Tags: c#, selenium

Please see the code below:

```
public static string GetRegion(IWebElement element, IWebDriver driver)
    {
            List<IWebElement> tree = new List<IWebElement>();
            try
            {
                tree.Add(element); 
                do
                {
                    element = element.FindElement(By.XPath("./parent::*")); //parent relative to current element
                    tree.Add(element);

                    if (element.GetAttribute("class").ToUpper() == "SomeClass")
                    {
                        var children = element.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*"));

                        foreach (var child in children)
                        {
                            if (child.GetAttribute("class").ToUpper() == "SomeOtherClass")
                            {
                                child.Click();
                                return child.Text;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } while (element.TagName != "body");
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
                throw;
            }
            throw new Exception();
        }
```

child.Click() causes the following exception if the element is not in the viewport i.e. because I have to scroll down:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: 'element click intercepted: Element <div class="SomeOtherClass">...</div> is not clickable at point (917, 915). Other element would receive the click: <a href="/Get_In_Touch">...</a>
```

There are plenty of elements on the webpage with a class of: SomeOtherClass.  Is there any way to go to this element before the click.  I have seen plenty of examples that show how to do this when there is an ID, but none when there is not an id.  I cannot add an id at the moment.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/nadvolod/2c5ce6c43b44fc2dc2a17cb34531597d, because you said it may be connected with scrool. Also about ID, if element do not have ID you can use xpath, or css or class name and so many other locators.

Comment: Use `action` class or `java scripts executor` to click on the element.

Comment: @KunduK, thanks - I will look into that.  Are you able to submit an answer?

Comment: @w0051977 : I have added an answer please check if this resolved your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `java scripts executor` to click

Instead of `child.Click();`
Try this

```
 IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
 js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", child );
```